# argparse: change argument from positional to optional in certain cases

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

My script has the following usage:

```
prog.py login password [--show]
```

`login` and `password` are positional arguments. However, I want to transform them into an optional if another argument (`-s` or `--show`) is specified. So, the usage will be:

```
prog.py --show [login] [password]
```

This is my code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(...)
parser.add_argument('login', help="User login")
parser.add_argument('password', help="User password")
parser.add_argument('-s', '--show', dest='show', action='store_true',
                    help="Show user login and password")
```

Example:

```
prog.py login=mylogin password=mypassword
```

This script saves `mylogin` and `mypassword` to the file named `authorization.txt`

However, `prog.py --show` should only retrieve information from `authorization.txt` without requiring `login` and `password` arguments and print current user login and password to stdout:

```
login: mylogin
password: mypassword
```

Comment: Giving examples for your use-case would help us understand your question better.

Comment: In your code `-s` and `--show` do the same thing, set the `args.dest` attribute to `True`.  Neither changes the parsing of the 2 required positionals.

Comment: Wouldn't the easiest way to handle this be to make the argument always optional, and then check if 'show' argument value is set to false , if so, check if vlaue for login and password is provided or not and throw error appropriately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have limited experience with argparse, so pinch of salt required, but here goes...

Positional arguments are **always** required. If your script does not explicitly require them for everything it needs to do, then, by definition, they are actually optional.

Also, argparse cannot handle changes to the argument structure on a whim. How is it supposed to know what arguments have been passed to it before `parser.parse_args()` is called?

With that in mind, I reckon `add_mutually_exclusive_group()` is what you might need https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion

The idea is two create two optional arguments, only one of which can be called at any one time:

```
prog.py --store [login password] --show
```

There's no way around these both being optional (yet, that I know of). If you set the `required` flag to `True`, argparse will always require one of these arguments to be presented when `prog.py` is run. So what we're *really* getting is some sort of quasi-optional-positional argument.

N.B. You can't add a description / help info to a mutually exclusive group... Bit of a pain.

**argparse code:**

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
exclusive_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
exclusive_group.add_argument('--store', dest='store', nargs=2, type=str,
                                 help="Store user login and password")
exclusive_group.add_argument('--show', dest='show', action='store_true',
                                 help="Show user login and password")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

**Running argparse code:**

```
$:python test.py --show
Namespace(show=True, store=None)

$:python test.py --store foo bar
Namespace(show=False, store=['foo', 'bar'])
```

**EDIT:**
I originally posted that `nargs` won't allow for an integer value to define the number of variables allowed, but thanks to @hpaulj for correction.

You can use `nargs=2`, which means `--store` must be given 2 arguments and provides an error if it doesn't get 2. The destination `store` is therefore a list of length 2. This negates any need for any extra code for validation of the number of variables, BUT, this doesn't protect against the ordering of the variables. As these are stored in a list, they could be input in any order... so be careful with that.

Comment: You can use `nargs=2`.

Comment: @hpaulj ah! I've always tried to do it as `nargs='2'`... This makes a lot more sense. Editing answer.